# Excel if with sumifs calculation result wrong

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I would like to know the amount from the same invoice. I tried with
`=IF(C20<>C19,SUMIF($C:$C,$C20,$Y:$Y),0)`
but the result are wrong.

What I need is to sum based on delivery order number, if the result is 0 then it means reverse documents.

Any advice?

Comment: is So amount Y:Y? and DO delivery order?

Comment: Your formula works maybe your Data or the columns are not the corresponding ones

Comment: yes. Y:Y is DO/SO/Invoice amount..

Comment: Is the number too large, or too small? In other words, is it picking up extra numbers, or is it failing to include some numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please provide an example of how the formula is failing. That is, show the data that should be added, what value should be returned, and what the formula is returning instead. I've spent a while looking at your screen capture, but it's missing information that would make it useful, namely column and row numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need the IF statement (the SUMIF already contains an IF statement). My guess is your IF only compares to the previous cell. If your data is unsorted, then it will not detect matches unless the same item just so happen to be next to each other.

SUMIF and SUMIFS are a great tool, but perhaps a pivot table is all you need...